# "Cuando te vas a viajar a Suiza"? is incorrect way of asking this question?

Tags: gramática

I asked a friend "Asi que cuando te vas a viajar a Suiza?", and he tells me that it sounded wrong to him (he is Spanish speaker and I am just learning it )

He argued that  "Asi que cuando te vas de viaje a Suiza?" O "Así que cuando vas a viajar a Suiza?" sound better ways of asking the question to him, and that "Así que cuando te vas a viajar a Suiza" Sounded wrong to him, but he could not give me the exact reason as to why he thinks my way of phrasing the question is wrong.

Any explanation as to the reason would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't going to answer because it's always difficult to explain why something is idiomatic or not in any language. But after thinking a bit about the reasons, I believe that I've found a good explanation.

Let's say that your company decides to move you temporarily to Athens to supervise the creation of the new Greek branch. You can announce that to your family and friends saying:

1. Voy a Grecia en diciembre [main verb: ir]
2. Me voy a Grecia en diciembre [main verb: ir(se)]
3. Me voy a ir a Grecia en diciembre [main verb: ir(se)]
4. Me voy a trasladar a Grecia en diciembre [main verb: trasladar(se)]
5. Me voy a desplazar a Grecia en diciembre [main verb: desplazarse(se)]

All sentences are valid and equivalent in this context. Did you see the pattern there? I've included **(se)** in most verbs because they are pronominal, we use them in most cases along with a reflexive pronoun that it's located before the verb in the sentence. And **[viajar](https://dle.rae.es/viajar) is not a pronominal verb**. We don't say:

a) Me viajo a Grecia en diciembre
b) Me voy a viajar a Grecia en diciembre

We can say:

i) Viajo a Grecia en diciembre
ii) Voy a viajar a Grecia en diciembre

That's the reason that we feel that it's awkward for you to ask

¿Cuándo **te** vas a viajar a Suiza?

On the other hand, like in English, there's no need to repeat the whole sentence in an interrogative form. I find that in any case your original question was too verbose. **In all correct cases (with or without viajar) presented above it's perfectly correct to just ask**:

¿Cuándo te vas?

P.S. Feel free to correct me if I used some non-idiomatic expression in English ;-P

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! Congratulations!

Comment: @Gustavson Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why:

(1) Así que, ¿cuándo te vas a viajar a Suiza?

is wrong, while:

(2) Así que, ¿cuándo te vas de viaje a Suiza?

or

(3) Así que, ¿cuándo vas a viajar a Suiza?"

are fine, is that in (1) "irse" is a pronominal verb meaning "leave" or "go out" that can only be used with adverbials of place or time or with infinitives indicating a specific activity (and suggesting the place where that activity is carried out) and **point to the present time if used in the present tense**.

For example, you might say the affirmative statements below, which point to the present:

- Chau, me voy a nadar. (Bye, I'm leaving for a swim.)
- Chau, me voy a estudiar. (Bye, I'm going to school, or I'm going to my office/room to study.)

What makes these questions awkward is the use of "when" (we cannot ask "when" to refer to the present):

- ¿Cuándo te vas a nadar? (awkward)
- ¿Cuándo te vas a estudiar? (awkward)

Instead, (2) and (3) point to the future:

(2) Así que, ¿cuándo te vas de viaje a Suiza? (So, when are you traveling to Switzerland?)

or

(3) Así que, ¿cuándo vas a viajar a Suiza?" (So, where are you going to travel to Switzerland?)

In (2), "irse de viaje" is a verb phrase meaning "leave on/for a trip".

In conclusion, a semantic inconsistency arises when, in a question with "when", pronominal "irse" is used with an infinitive. "Irse" can only be used with an infinitive to indicate present time, in which case "when"-questions are not allowed.

I think I've found another reason why "irse a viajar" is not idiomatic. This has to do with a semantic overlap. We can say:

- Me voy a esquiar a Suiza. (I'm going skiing to Switzerland). Notice that this is equivalent to: Me voy a Suiza a esquiar (I'm going to Switzerland for skiing)

but we cannot say:

- Me voy a viajar a Suiza, because both actions overlap with the same adverbial of place: I'm going to Switzerland, I'm traveling to Switzerland. We cannot say: I'm going to Switzerland for traveling.

Comment: I think that the main difference here is "ir(se) a + infinitivo" vs "irse de viaje". You pointed that out already. But for me the awkward element would be "irse a viajar". "Mañana me voy a viajar a Suiza" is not idiomatic per se, so you can't have "¿Cuándo te vas a viajar a Suiza?". On the other hand for me it's perfectly correct "¿Cuándo te vas a nadar?", it can be use instead of "¿A qué hora te vas a nadar?"

Comment: Yes, ¿cuánto te vas a nadar? could work because "a nadar" indicates a specific action at a specific place. "Irse a nadar" can be equivalent to "ir a la piscina", "ir al río/mar", while "irse a viajar" cannot be transformed similarly and, as a result, does not work.

Comment: I have no answer for OP's question. What I'm trying to tell you is that you have pointed two sentences as awkward while from my point of view (as per my example) they are valid: 
¿Cuándo te vas a nadar? (awkward) [no, it's correct]
¿Cuándo te vas a estudiar? (awkward)  [no, it's correct]

Comment: Sin cultural gap: Que yo creo que tu respuesta está bien orientada, pero que hay algunos puntos que flaquean.